# How do I check if a hex color in an NSString is light or dark in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have found answers to this question that explain how to convert an NSString hex into a UIColor (I have done this) and others explaining how to convert RGB to HSB, and others explaining how to determine lightness and darkness of RGB, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way of figuring this out that does not involve going hex->UIColor->rgb->hsb->b.
Hex->hsb, for instance? Or hex->rgb->brightness calculation?

I've got backgrounds that change color each time the view loads (hex values from XML), and I need to have the text on top change to white or black accordingly so it'll stay legible.

Help would be much appreciated, I've been kicking this around for days now.

Comment: what format is your hex colors in?

Comment: Not sure I'm answering this right, but standard web colors, eg "#F2AA6B" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color).

Hex colors are usually RRGGBB or RRGGBBAA (alpha).

[how to convert hexadecimal to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265161/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-to-rgb)

To get three ints instead of a UIColor, you can modify the answer from that to:

```
void rgb_from_hex(char *hexstring, int *red, int *green, int *blue) {
    // convert everything after the # into a number
    long x = strtol(hexstring+1, NULL, 16);

    // extract the bytes
    *blue = x & 0xFF;
    *green = (x >> 8) & 0xFF;
    *red = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

// The above function is used like this:
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int r,g,b;
    rgb_from_hex("#123456", &r, &g, &b);
    printf("r=%d, g=%d, b=%d\n", r, g, b);
}
```

(The function will probably only correctly handle RGB, not RGBA.)

Comment: I was looking at the hex to RGB question earlier, but the answers seem to convert hex to UIColor. Is UIColor the same as RGB, eg can I access the R,G and B components separately from UIColor?

Comment: From the docs, it seems like UIColor wraps CGColor, which is fairly opaque and doesn't do colourspace conversions.

Comment: In that case, I'm still missing a way to convert hex to RGB values(four int values (r, g, b, a), for instance?), while not involving UIColor at all. The answers to the question referenced above take you directly to UIColor from the hex string. (or perhaps converting from hex NSString to rgb ints is so simple that no one has thought to mention how it's done?)

Comment: The linked answer /does/ convert to three RGB ints, it just wraps them inside a UIColor at the very end. It should be reasonably easy to wrap them in an int[] instead.

Comment: @spongefile: Right, I (somehow) managed to make working C to do the conversion, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of the red, green, and blue components seems to determine the "brightness" of a color in the HSB sense.

Comment: If that was the case, white (#ffffff) would have the same brightness as blue (#0000ff).

Comment: It does. It just has a different saturation. The HSV colorspace does not model colour appearance, it's just a mapping of RGB to a different set of axes.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I was thinking of the perceived luminance. Sorry about the downvote, it seems that I can't remove it unless the answer is edited.

Comment: This is actually an interesting point--I had assumed(and so had others in previous questions) that in HSB, brightness is the same as "lightness", eg what looks light or dark to the eye. Looks like saturation is what I'm looking for. Edit: wrong again. Saturation limit PLUS brightness limit.

Comment: @spongefile: Searching around gave me [this blog post](http://www.destraynor.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/140-Crimes-Against-Web-Usability-2.html), which deals with the same problem you have. It also lists a guideline on the recommended brightness and hue difference, so you can, for example, prefer black text if it's "good enough" even if white text gives numerically more contrast. (I believe the formula is the same one as one of those Jacob linked to.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, this is another solution, put together from others' answers here and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620231/how-do-i-convert-a-hex-color-in-an-nsstring-to-three-separate-rgb-ints-in-objecti) .

```
    - (BOOL)hasDkBg {    
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"BD8F60"];
        int hex;
        if ([scanner scanHexInt:&hex]) {
            // Parsing successful. We have a big int representing the 0xBD8F60 value
            int r = (hex >> 16) & 0xFF; // get the first byte
            int g = (hex >>  8) & 0xFF; // get the middle byte
            int b = (hex      ) & 0xFF; // get the last byte

            int lightness = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000; //get lightness value

    if (lightness < 127) { //127 = middle of possible lightness value
        return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}
```

}