# Change Background color according to the webservice data

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, background-color

I have a webservice which has R,G,B,alpha value,
I parsed the values.
How to set this value

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:value green:value1 blue:value2 alpha:value3]];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: yes this is possible.

Comment: What is your exact question? you can create colour from RGBA values and use it to set background colour.

Comment: try this  [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:value1/255.0 green:value2/255.0 blue:value3/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];

Comment: what is the range of values in your web service?

Comment: This link helps me to over come
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265161/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-to-rgb

Answer (score 0):

If your R, G and B values range from 0 to 255, just... divide them by 255 and feed them to `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` (alpha is 1.0 for a fully opaque color).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible , the following is the way for implementing this

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) value/255.0) green:((float) value1/255.0) blue:((float) value2/255.0) alpha:(float)value3]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:value/255.0f green:value1/255.0f blue:value2/255.0f alpha:value3]];
```

instead of

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:value green:value1 blue:value2 alpha:value3]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
CGFloat value = 204.0f;
CGFloat value2 = 234.0f;
CGFloat value1 = 254.0f;
CGFloat value3 = 1.0f;
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:value/255.0 green:value1/255.0  blue:value2/255.0 alpha:value3]];
```