# Get color hex from colorWithHue

Tags: ios, uicolor

I can get color hex from RGB.
Now, is there any way to get color hex from `colorWithHue`?

```
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:180.0f / 360.0f    saturation:0.02f    brightness:0.85f    alpha:0.8f];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link does a good job showing you how to! It also has several code snippets! :-) You can also use the calculator on the same website to check if your calculations are correct!

[The Link](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method too i guess: [How can I get a hex string from UIColor or from rgb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051807/how-can-i-get-a-hex-string-from-uicolor-or-from-rgb)

```
- (NSString *)hexStringForColor:(UIColor *)color {
      const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
      CGFloat r = components[0];
      CGFloat g = components[1];
      CGFloat b = components[2];
      NSString *hexString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X", (int)(r * 255), (int)(g * 255), (int)(b * 255)];
      return hexString;
}
```

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:180.0f / 360.0f saturation:0.02f brightness:0.85f alpha:0.8f];
return [self hexStringForColor:color];

Answer (score 0):

colorWithHue method of UIColor class returns an UIColor object. You can then use the following category to get the hex code.

https://github.com/burhanuddin353/TFTColor

```
[UIColor hexStringForColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:180/360.0f saturation:0.02f brightness:0.85f alpha:0.8f]];
```