# how to Compare two CGColor in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, swift4, cgcolor

Basically all I want to do is to compare a `layer.fillColor` which is a `CGColor` with `UIColor.black.cgColor`.

The function `CGColorEqualToColor` is now deprecated in Swift 4.

I have tried:

```
if(layer.fillColor === UIColor.black.cgColor){
          return      
}
```

And it still doesn't work. I guess they must have the same kCGColorSpaceModel.

This is the output of each color in logs

```
<CGColor 0x1c02a15c0> [<CGColorSpace 0x1c02a0a20> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0 0 0 1 )
<CGColor 0x1c008e290> [<CGColorSpace 0x1c02a0f60> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile; extended range)] ( 0 1 )
```

What's the solution?

Comment: Implement a [color difference measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). If you limit yourself to RGB or sRGB, it's pretty simple

Comment: `CGColorEqualToColor` has the same problem as `==` in that it checks the colour space, so it wouldn't help if it wasn't deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension for `CGColor` that checks if the given color is black or not. This works with colors in the RGB and greyscale color spaces.

```
extension CGColor {
    func isBlack() -> Bool {
        let count = numberOfComponents
        if count > 1 {
            if let components = components {
                for c in 0..<components.count-1 { // skip the alpha component
                    // All components are 0 for black
                    if components[c] != 0.0 {
                        return false
                    }
                }

                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}

print(UIColor.black.cgColor.isBlack())
print(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor.isBlack())
```

You can use this as:

```
if layer.fillColor.isBlack() {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CGColor` has a method [converted(to:intent:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455493-converted)

So maybe you could have a method as follows:

```
extension CGColor
{
    func compareConvertingColorSpace(other: CGColor) -> Bool 
    {
        let approximateColor = other.converted(to: self.colorSpace! intent: .defaultIntent, options nil) // fatal errror with no color space
        return self == approximateColor 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension CGColor {
    func same(as another: CGColor) -> Bool {
        let components = components ?? []
        let anotherComponents = another.components ?? []
        return zip(components, anotherComponents).allSatisfy { abs($0 - $1) < 1e-4 }
    }
}
```

You can use this as:

`let sameBorderColor:Bool = borderColor.isSame(as: testBorderColor)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the 2 colours to Strings and then compare them normal. To convert them to strings, there is an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/14051861/3342901.