# Union and endianness

Tags: c, cpu, endianness

```
typedef union status
{
    int nri;
    char cit[2];
}Status;

int main()  {
    Status s;
    s.nri = 1;
    printf("%d \n",s.nri);
    printf("%d,%d,\n",s.cit[0],s.cit[1]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
0,1
```

I know this output on the second line is depend on the endianess of the CPU. How I can write such in a platform-independant program? Is there any way of checking the endianess of the CPU?

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: Depending upon the endianness, output in second line will change, right? I want to write this code which is platform independant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`htonl()` and/or `ntohl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl). `htonl()` stands for "host to network long", while `ntohl()` stands for "network to host long". The "host" and "network" refers to the byte order. Network byte order is "big-endian". The operations will be no-ops if the host platform is also "big-endian". Using these routines, the following program will always report the same output:

```
uint32_t x = htonl(1);
unsigned char *p = (void *)&x;
printf("%u %u %u %u\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
uint32_t y = ntohl(x);
assert(y == 1);
```

Comment: If you use OS-specific functions, then what's the point of writing endian-independent code?

Comment: @Lundin: They are POSIX functions. It is also part of Winsock.

Comment: There is nothing in the original post indicating that they even have an OS... Anyway, it isn't particularly hard to write an endian check yourself, you don't need to involve some API function. `int a = 0xAABBCCDD; if(*(uint8_t*)&a == 0xAA) puts("big") else puts("little");`.

Comment: @Lundin: If I was writing platform independent code for multiple platforms that didn't have an OS, the first task would be to port an OS to each platform.

Comment: No you wouldn't, if one of the platforms was an embedded system. It is common practice to take the code intended for such systems and put it in your PC, to create & run tests on it.

Comment: @Lundin: Small embedded software development (like for a toaster oven) is typically targeted for a single platform, and is rarely portable. This is why embedded developers use hardware simulators or VM environments for their testing.  Multi-platform embedded development happens for larger or older systems where older hardware still requires support. On those platforms, there is always an embedded OS to go with the system (like VxWorks, QNX, embedded Linux, or something homegrown).

Comment: completely off topic, but i don't see why you need an OS for a toaster. nobody will install applications or plug a sound card and update drivers. you don't need to treat interruptions, and no multitasking, no network... An OS would take memory, licensing issues, boot up time.. that would be bad overengineering.

Comment: @jxh nicely and clearly written patent. Often one does not even understand wth people are taking about in patents. But I think this goes my way; because nowhere an OS is mentioned.

Comment: @v.oddou: *It is still a further object of the invention to provide a control system for toaster oven appliances which is implemented with a programmed micro-processor.* I.e., an operating system.

Comment: @jxh !? I wonder how an engineer like you could mix up terminology so badly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microprocessor

Comment: @v.ouddou: Perhaps you have no memory of the days when the operating system was just a program in ROM that performed a few simple services, like accept input and display output. See ***programmed microprocessor***.

Answer (score 2):

If you want endian-independent code, then you want platform-indepentent code as well, otherwise your requirements don't make sense. Code which does not rely on endianess cannot rely of the size of an int, nor on the signedness of char.

To get something truly portable, I suppose you would have to write something similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int) * 8)

#define BYTE0_MASK (0xFFu << (INT_BITS -  8))
#define BYTE1_MASK (0xFFu << (INT_BITS - 16))

int main()
{
  int i = 0xAABBCCDD;
  unsigned char arr [2] =
  {
    (i & BYTE0_MASK) >> (INT_BITS -  8),
    (i & BYTE1_MASK) >> (INT_BITS - 16)
  };

  printf("%x %x", arr[0], arr[1]);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Endianness is usually not an issue if your program does not communicate with other program (including the same program written for another platform), unless you do something very special like the union defined in your question. When your program does communicate with other programs, like saving binary data into a file, sending data in a socket, it'd be better to define the endianness clearly in the format/protocol. Alternatively you can also transmit the data in textual form.