# C++14 : endianness at compile-time with constexpr?

Tags: c++, endianness, constexpr, c++14

With the relaxation of constraints on constant expression, is there a way in C++14 to obtain the system endianness at compile-time ?

```
constexpr bool is_big_endian()
{
    // Something here
}

constexpr bool is_little_endian()
{
    // Something here
}
```

Comment: I haven't heard of a constant for that but you can get the common #define the compiler will give you about the architecture. If you're going to make it work on different architectures you should know their endianness so you can easily use some #ifdef

Comment: A `reinterpret_cast` is still not allowed in constant expressions; and you can still write "endian-independent" code with shift-operators.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239993/determining-endianness-at-compile-time

Comment: other ways: http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=5095 https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-07/msg00342.html or the [predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__`, `__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__` in gcc

Comment: How about without boost? does a `union` help of `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed?

Comment: using a `union` http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431286/472245