# Finding endian-ness programmatically at compile-time using C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, endianness, compile-time, type-punning

I have referred many questions in SO on this topic, but couldn't find any solution so far. One natural solution was mentioned here: [Determining endianness at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24431286/514235).
However, the related problems mentioned in the comments & the same answer.

With some modifications, I am able to compile a similar solution with g++ & clang++ (`-std=c++11`) without any warning.

```
static_assert(sizeof(char) == 1, "sizeof(char) != 1");
union U1
{
  int i;
  char c[sizeof(int)];
};  
union U2
{ 
  char c[sizeof(int)];
  int i;
};  

constexpr U1 u1 = {1};
constexpr U2 u2 = {{1}};
constexpr bool IsLittleEndian ()
{ 
  return u1.i == u2.c[0];  // ignore different type comparison
}   

static_assert(IsLittleEndian(), "The machine is BIG endian");
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/TtKRWQ).

Can this be considered a deterministic method to decide the endian-ness or does it miss type-punning or something else?

Comment: Doesn't `uint8_t(u2.i)` produce the same value on either endianness? A cast should be value preserving, not just pick the first byte.

Comment: There are 24 possible orderings of bytes within a 4-byte integer.  At *least* three have been used by real computers.  Also, it is not entirely clear that the exception to the strict aliasing rules granted to [[`un`]`signed`] `char` applies to `uint8_t`.

Comment: @BoPersson, I wanted to avoid any possible compiler warning related to "comparison of different size types" (as I try to claim in the Q!). Since here, 1 will be representable with the smallest type, I found it to be acceptable for typecasting. Or did I misunderstood your concern? I will modify the code a bit.

Comment: I belive that if you actually run this on a big endian machine, it would still test if `1 == 1` and return `true`.

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` is true by definition. `sizeof` is given in *units of `char`,* so this assertion can literally never fail.

Comment: Quite sure there is no way to use `constexpr` to do this, since any `union`/`reinterpret_cast` approach invokes UB (which is caught at compile time inside a `constexpr`), and `memcpy` is not `constexpr`.
Compiler specific macros are the only way around it (look for __BYTE_ORDER).

Comment: @sbabbi, not sure why `union` will cause UB. It doesn't generate any warning in either g++/clang++. BTW, regarding compiler specific macros, there is a platform specific file supported, `<endian.h>`, as mentioned in this answer: [C Macro definition to determine big endian or little endian machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2100363/514235)

Comment: @iammilind See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior . IIRC gcc defines the behavior (of accessing a non-active union member, basically they promise they are not going to optimize on this), but it is UB in the standard.

Comment: One easy way to find endianness at compile time in C++, is to just use OS macro sniffing. There's a nice collection of OS-indicator macros over at some SourceForge project. Yes, as the site indicates it's old, so maybe all the Androids are not covered, but it should be doable.

Comment: Planned proposal: http://howardhinnant.github.io/endian.html

Comment: @HowardHinnant, nice to see the proposal. As a common C++ coder, I feel it to be little complex though. May be you can explain in that blog that why is 'simply defining `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` (& big, native)' not enough? IMO, enum trick is trivial and hence not needed.

Comment: Afaik, what you want is not possible. If you *must* have that information at compile time, consider using a trivial, short test program that outputs either `const char* const ENDIANESS = "little";` or `const char* const ENDIANESS = "big";` into a file "endianess.h", which is then used by your actual source code.

Comment: Also note, that there are other byte orders than just little endian or big endian out there. Braindead stuff like `0x01020304` being stored as `0x03 0x04 0x01 0x02`. So, if I were you, I would write the test with `char[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};`, copy over to at least a `uint64_t`, and then check for equality with either `0x0102030405060708` or `0x0807060504030201`. If neither test succeeds, you should probably error out *hard*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++20 you can use [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) from the `<type_traits>` header:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::endian::native==std::endian::big,
                  "Not a big endian platform!");
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e626468b1dd8a452)

Comment: Are you from the future?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is no different from this obviously non-working one (where `IsLittleEndian()` is identical to `true`):

```
constexpr char c[sizeof(int)] = {1};
constexpr int i = {1};
constexpr bool IsLittleEndian ()
{ 
  return i == c[0];  // ignore different type comparison
}   

static_assert(IsLittleEndian(), "The machine is BIG endian");
```

I believe that C++11 doesn't provide means to programatically determine the endianness of the target platform during compile time. My argument is that the only valid way to perform that check **during runtime** is to examine an `int` variable using an `unsigned char` pointer (since other ways of type punning inevitably contain undefined behavior):

```
const uint32_t i = 0xffff0000;

bool isLittleEndian() {
    return 0 == *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&i);
}
```

C++11 doesn't allow to make this function `constexpr`, therefore this check cannot be performed during compile time.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about why the attempted solution will not work? Or why is it same as the one you mentioned (non-working) in beginning of answer. I haven't got a chance to check on a big-endian machine, however I assume that what you said is true. But the question is Why?

Comment: @iammilind What purpose do the unions serve in your "solution"? You never access/use `U1::c` and you never access/use `U2::i`. Hence, after eliminating them we arrive at my version.

Comment: The 2 unions are to just eliminate compiler error, which comes otherwise with 1 union. If you check `u1.i == u1.c[0]` (same for `u2`) then it works fine. This solution is in many other answers in SO. But those are limited to runtime. They don't work compile time because of `constexpr` limitations. Here U1 & U2 act as mirror to each other. I have attempted to trick the compiler to allow it for compile time. May be it is wrong. But good if someone checks it in big endian.

Comment: @iammilind I understand that. But if you forget the prehistory of how you arrived at your version, doesn't the existence of `U1::c` and `U2::i` appear to be completely artificial?

Comment: @iammilind: The way I understand the initialization in `U2 u2 = {{1}}` is that it always sets first item of array to `1`. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Cheers, correct. But now I do understand that without making a comparison with other member of `union`, the purpose is not served. And according to C++11, accessing a union member which is *not* set latest, is undefined; though supported by many. For that much part we have to have a .c file/function, which will at least give runtime type info.

Comment: BTW, C++ 20 finally addresses this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian