# How to concatenate the hexadecimal data in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, hex, concatenation

I have my data field as follows `DATA = 0x02 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07` Now I want to concatenate this data as follows `DATA = 0x01020304050607`. How can I do it using C program. I found a program in C for concatenation of data in an array and the program is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num[3]={1, 2, 3}, n1, n2, new_num;
    n1 = num[0] * 100;
    n2 = num[1] * 10;
    new_num = n1 + n2 + num[2];
    printf("%d \n", new_num);
    return 0;
}
```

For the hexadecimal data in the array how can I manipulate the above program to concatenate the hexadecimal data?

Comment: `printf("%x", (unsigned int)((n[0] << 16) + (n[1] << 8) + n[2]));`

Comment: Is that meant to be `char num[3]={1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: Well, the easiest way is `const unsigned char data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ...};` - and all these elements will be stored in a consecutive segment of memory, one after the other, in this very order.

Comment: `DATA = 0x01020304050607` needs a 64-bit variable. Or even `DATA = 0x0201020304050607` depending on which version you want.

Comment: data[] is of type `uint8_t  data[8];` and cannot be `unsigned char`

Comment: @user8540390 where is `data[8]` ?

Comment: You have 8 values in your initial version of `DATA`, but you ignore the leading `0x02` value when concatenating the data.  What is the basis for deciding to ignore that value?  Or is that a typo for `0x00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 64 bit variable `num` as result, instead of `10` as factor you need `16`, and instead of `100` as factor, you need `256`.

But if your data is provided as an array of bytes, then you can simply insert complete bytes, i.e. repeatedly shifting by 8 bits (meaning a factor of 256):

```
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t data[8] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };
    unsigned long long num = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        num <<=8;  // shift by a complete byte, equal to num *= 256
        num |= data[i];  // write the respective byte
    }
    printf("num is %016llx\n",num);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
num is 0201020304050607
```

Comment: The conversion format `%llx` might not be appropriate for `uint64_t`. You should cast the operand as `unsigned long long`, or simply use this type for `num` as it is specified as having at least 64 value bits.

Answer (score 1):

Lest say you have input like

```
int DATA[8] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07};
```

If you want output like `0x0001020304050607`, to store this resultant output you need one variable of `unsigned long long` type. For e.g

```
int main(void) {
        int DATA[8] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07};
        int ele = sizeof(DATA)/sizeof(DATA[0]);
        unsigned long long mask = 0x00;
        for(int row = 0; row < ele; row++) {
                mask = mask << 8;/* every time left shifted by 8(0x01-> 0000 0001) times   */
                mask = DATA[row] | mask; /* put at correct location */
        }
        printf("%016llx\n",mask);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some kind of hack that writes your data directly into an integer, without any bitwise operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uint64_t numberize(const uint8_t from[8]) {
    uint64_t r = 0;
    uint8_t *p = &r;

    #if '01' == 0x4849 // big endian
        memcpy(p, from, 8);
    #else // little endian
        for (int i=7; i >= 0; --i)
            *p++ = from[i];     
    #endif

    return r;
}

int main() {
    const uint8_t data[8] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };

    printf("result is %016llx\n", numberize(data));

    return 0;
}
```

This [does work](https://ideone.com/m19JDi) and outputs this independently of the endianness of your machine:

```
result is 0201020304050607
```

<sup>The compile-time endianness test was taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240036/4354477).</sup>

Comment: The preprocessor endianness test is unreliable and unspecified per the C Standard. You can use a runtime check that will be optimized out by the compiler, or you can use a simple and readable loop: `int i; uint64_t r = 0; for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { r = (r << 8) | from[i]; } return r;`

Comment: The conversion format `%llx` might not be appropriate for `uint64_t`. You should cast the operand as `unsigned long long`.