# `dirent.h` in multiple directories

Tags: c, macos

I searched `dirent` to find C routines

```
find / -iregex ".*/dirent.h$" 2>/dev/null
```

Which return series of identical ones

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/dirent.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/dirent.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h
```

How could I ensure which `dirent.h` is the one my program invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the compiler to show you the code after pre-processing, you should be able to work it out.

So, for example, with `gcc`, you can write a nominal `program.c`:

```
#include <dirent.h>
main(int argc, char **argv){
    return 0;
}
```

And then run:

```
gcc -E program.c
```

and study what it includes.

Related useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054190/2836621).