# Compile time endian dependent expressions?

Tags: c, constants, endianness, compile-time

While implementing UDP BitTorrent tracker protocol, I noticed that most common packet parsing step is checking whether first 64 bits are protocol id `0x41727101980`, used for requesting a connection, before falling back to assumption that it's one of given out connection ids.

I realize that endianness of connection id doesn't really matter when it's just being used as unique sequence of bits and so I had an idea to simply not convert it from network byte order to host, but simply use those values as is, but there's just one problem, protocol id, as written, will not match protocol id in the packet which is encoded in big endian, unless the code is running on big endian machine, so I have to convert the first 64bits somewhere all the time anyway.

I know that I could convert the value once at runtime, but maybe there's some hack that allows expressing this value `0x41727101980` in a `uint64_t` which ensures that no matter the system's endianness, it will always be encoded in big endian?

What I exactly want to know is if equivalent of:

```
static uint64_t const PROTOCOL_ID = htobe64(0x41727101980);
```

is possible at compile time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining endianness at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239993/determining-endianness-at-compile-time)

Comment: 5 and a half byte is not 64 bits... nor is it likely the format of the IP package either...

Comment: @BurnsBA no it doesn't, I don't want to determine endianness at compile time, I want to define a constant as if I was on big endian machine, regardless of what spaghetti endianness the code is on.

Comment: @Lundin it's a constant, used in protocol that stands on top of UDP, even if it was 0x1 it would be a valid 64 bit number, not sure how is that relevant to the question though.

Comment: Because if it is exactly 5 and a half bytes in the actual protocol, the constant in your program needs to reflect that. Otherwise if it is 8 bytes, you'd write a different program.

Comment: Both your question body and title ask to determine endieness at compile time, if that's not what you're asking you need to update the question.

Comment: @BurnsBA neither my question nor its title has "determine endianness at compile time" anywhere, I even wrote a single line of code illustrating that.

Comment: Don’t suppose `static uint8_t const PROTOCOL_ID[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x17, 0x27, 0x10, 0x19, 0x80};` works for you? Why do you need this at compile time, by the way? Because on the off chance that it’s for performance, note that compilers optimize away `htobe64` to a constant already.

Comment: Your question is strictly equivalent to determining endianness at compile time. If you can determine endianness at compile time, you can create an integer with a given byte representation at compile time; and if you can create an integer with a given byte representation at compile time, you can determine endianness at compile time.

Comment: @Ry- code readability, if I have to call memcmp to be very intelligent and different from others when working with a network byte ordered buffer, I may aswell call htobe64 like you say. But that's besides the point, I guess the lesson here for me is if I want to have performance AND code readability, I shouldn't use C, but something like C++ instead.

Comment: That' because I do know better than yourself about the question you are asking (shocking I know), If you tried to think for one second, you would understand that little-endian ARM and big-endian ARM are two different architectures. Code compiled for one cannot run on the other, and vice versa. Being able to switch between the architectures on reboot has nothing to do with the problem. The physical chip doesn't matter, the architecture it runs does. But whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI so since you know better than me what question I'm asking, consider writing appropriate answer.

Comment: There is already a good answer. I was answering your comment "no it doesn't, I don't want to determine endianness at compile time", which is erroneous. I will spell it out this time. If you have  a `consteval` `htobe64`, then you can have `consteval bool is_big_endian() { return  0x0102030405060708 == htobe64(0x0102030405060708); }`. Conversely if you have `consteval bool is_big_endian()`, then `consteval` `htobe64` is also easy to write. But the real answer is that you don't need these. Use an array of bytes and `memcmp`. The compiler is likely to optimise it out.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI If I have `consteval bool is_big_endian` then I know for a fact that it will almost always be false and I can't be sure what kind it is (little endian isn't the only one that's not big endian). I also know that it's C++ and this question is tagged with C explicitly but after all you know things better than I do so you will keep spamming your garbage like ChatGPT without a thought. Seriously, when I registered on this website I intended to get a clear "no" or "yes, this is how", but instead it feels like reddit for when god complex is too huge to use actual reddit.

Comment: My bad, I didn't look a the tag, for which I apologize. Replace consteval with the non-standard `__attribute__ ((const))` or whatever you like. If you think my comments should not be there, flag them. I will continue to leave comments that I think are useful for other readers, even if you might not like them. But perhaps not in this thread.

Comment: I think you ignored the rest of my comment, underestimate compilers (which will easily optimize `memcmp` to a single instruction and `htobe64(constant)` on a constant, so just write the option you find readable and *check* whether there’s a non-imagined problem), and overestimate how coherent your question is.

Comment: Because as it stands, there's always a genius, until real work needs to be done. I already got my answer: **No, it isn't possible**. Thank you for taking 3 whole days to tell me.

Comment: Of course it’s possible, it’s just pointless and you asked an XY question.

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge: you don't want to actually want a compile time endian dependent expression.  You really want a sequence of bytes.

So define your protocol ID as:

```
static const uint8_t PROTOCOL_ID[8] = {0x0,0x0,0x4,0x17,0x27,0x10,0x19,0x80};
```

And then use `memcmp` to compare this to the start of your UDP buffer.  This is safer than what I suspect you're doing, namely converting the start of your buffer to a `uint64_t *`, dereferencing, and comparing to another `uint64_t` which could run afoul of strict aliasing and alignment issues.

Comment: I always `memcpy(&bits64, buf + offset, sizeof(bits64));`, which optionally leads to `bits64 = be64toh(bits64);`, it just would've been nice to be able to do `bits64 == 0x41727101980` directly. I trust my compiler to replace be64toh with a mere bswap instruction on most processors, so `memcmp` would need to be investigated for sizes that are pointer size or smaller, it's likely no difference, just more obscure code. I'm also aware of having a global variable that I initialize in main with a runtime be64toh but that's another wart to keep track of.