# How I can calculate complex function in compile time?

Tags: c++, compilation, macros, endianness

I need to get little endian binary data, so at big endian computers I convert it to little endian by doing this

```cpp
bool IsBigEndian() {
  int i = 1;

  return ((*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&i)) == 0);
}
uint32_t Reverse(uint32_t value) {
  uint32_t result;
  uint8_t* pointer_to_result = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&result);
  uint8_t* pointer_to_value = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&value);
  pointer_to_result[0] = pointer_to_value[3];
  pointer_to_result[1] = pointer_to_value[2];
  pointer_to_result[2] = pointer_to_value[1];
  pointer_to_result[3] = pointer_to_value[0];
  return result;
}
void WriteInLittleEndian(std::ofstream& file, uint32_t value) {
  if (IsBigEndian()) value = Reverse(value);
  file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}
```

How I can not calculate it every time I need to get Little Endian value but calculate it at compile time and use macro to write plain data at little endian machines and reversed at big endian?

Comment: where is `value` coming from? If it is only known at runtime, you cannot convert it at compile time. Or are you looking for a look up table?

Comment: [This is probably worth a read.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239993/determining-endianness-at-compile-time)

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` between unrelated types is unspecified behavior, then if you use this value, it is undefined behavior. Since things evaluated at compile time must report error in case of UB, i Think this is root cause of your problem.

Comment: Is "it" the result of `IsBigEndian` or the result of `Reverse`?

Comment: value coming from runtime, but i want to get function WriteInLittleEndian in compile time without calling IsBigEndian every time

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration in [std::endian](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) and [std::byteswap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap).

Comment: Use constexpr and get rid of all the pointers. However calculation at compile time is not going to work when your input data is only known at runtime

Comment: Get rid of endianess condition, and use value instead of representation: `const uint8_t buf{ value & 0xFF, (value >> 8u) & 0xFF, (value >> 16) & 0xFF, (value >> 24) & 0xFF }; file.write(buff, sizeof (buff));`.

Comment: If you don't want to call `IsBigEndian` multiple times, just use it to initialize a `static bool const`. (Or just define it as a macro, depending on the target platform.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that the compile machine and the runtime machine are different machines.

To be able to compile this function to eliminate endianness dependency on runtime you could use build profiles that include the architecture you are compiling for. These profiles and how they work will change depending on your IDE and compiler.

Once that is set, you can include precompile directives to infer endianness at compile time. As a little example:

```cpp
#if defined(BIGENDIAN_ARCH1) | (BIGENDIAN_ARCH2)
    #define BIGENDIAN
#endif

...

void Write(std::ofstream& file, uint32_t value)
{
#ifdef BIGENDIAN
  uint32_t result;
  uint8_t* pointer_to_result = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&result);
  uint8_t* pointer_to_value = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&value);
  pointer_to_result[0] = pointer_to_value[3];
  pointer_to_result[1] = pointer_to_value[2];
  pointer_to_result[2] = pointer_to_value[1];
  pointer_to_result[3] = pointer_to_value[0];
  value = result;
#endif

  file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}
```

In the example, BIGENDIAN_ARCH1 and BIGENDIAN_ARCH2 are architectures that use big endianness. This means that your code must contain all the target architectures you are interested in compiling for.

Answer (score 0):

On convetional platform with straight big/little endian structure, below snippet works. But if you're dealing with special architectures with mixed endians(very rare corner cases), you need to come up with a more complicated implementation:

```
#include <std::array>
//This c++20 std header is essential:
#include <bit>
//This header makes it simpler:
#include <ranges>

template<typename bt, typename from>
requires ( sizeof(std::array<bt, sizeof(from)>) == sizeof(from)
         , std::is_trivially_copyable_v<bt>
         , std::is_trivially_copyable_v<from> )
constexpr auto host2net (from const& input)
 -> std::array<bt, sizeof(from)> {
    auto arr = std::bit_cast<std::array<bt, sizeof(from)>>(input);
    if (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
     // convert to little endian:
        std::ranges::reverse(arr);
    return arr;
};

std::uint64_t ui64 {/*some_64_bits()*/};
auto buff = host2net<char /*std::byte*/>(ui64);
file.write(data(buff), size(buff);
```

`std::bit_cast` is the recommended casting utility for converting between **trivial types**. It can be used in compile time evaluated contexts.
`std::byte` is supposed to be used wherever bytes are not assumed to be characters or integers; it is an eunum class with bit manipulation operators enabaled.
You may need to define an inverse to the above function as well:

```
template<typename to, typename bt>
requires ( sizeof(std::array<bt, sizeof(to)>) == sizeof(to)
         , std::is_trivially_copyable_v<bt>
         , std::is_trivially_copyable_v<to> )
constexpr to net2host (std::array<bt, sizeof(to)> input){
    if (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
     // convert to big endian:
        std::ranges::reverse(input);
    return std::bit_cast<to>(input);
};

std::array<char, sizeof(std::uint64_t)> buff;
file.read(data(buff), size(buff));
auto const ui64 = net2host<std::uint64_t>(buff);
```

I guess all your doubts and blanks should have been covered by the above snippets.