# Are wide characters string literals encoded in UTF-16LE?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Say I have the following:

```
wchar_t *str = L"Hello World!";
```

Is `L"Hello World!"` encoded in UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE?

**Note:** I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your editor, VS2010 uses UTF-8 by default :)  With a BOM so the compiler can tell.  It can be changed, click the arrow on the Save button.

The compiler will turn it into UTF-16LE in the object file, there are no remaining big-endian machines supported by msvc++ that I know of, ARM cores all run little-endian these days.

Answer (score 4):

You can safely assume that any wide character string on Windows uses little endian UTF-16 - see this answer for a more elaborate dive: [Can I safely assume that Windows installations will always be little-endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449468/can-i-safely-assume-that-windows-installations-will-always-be-little-endian)