# Checking byte order using preprocessor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I found the following code to check the byte order state. It works with VS C++:

```
#if '1234' != 0x31323334
#  define BIG_ENDIAN
#endif
```

I don't know if it works with other compilers. I would ask if it is a standard code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Macro definition to determine big endian or little endian machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine)

Comment: Whoever wrote that macro is confused.  `'1234' == 0x31323334` is true on most little endian **and** big endian implementations.  (For most C implementations, they're just different ways of writing the same number, and byte order simply doesn't factor into it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character constant with more than one character, such as `'1234'`, has an implementation-defined value.  There is absolutely no guarantee about the relationship between the value of `'1234'` and the system's endianness.

The preprocessor just doesn't have enough information to determine the target system's byte order.

And keep in mind that big-endian and little-endian aren't the only possibilities.  For a 4-byte integer type, there are 24 (4 factorial) possible byte orderings.  All of them are permitted by the language, and *at least* 3 of them have been used by real machines.