# C Big Endian to Little Endian Structure

Tags: c, struct, endianness

I have a struct that is defined as:

```
struct record
{
   int age;
   char name[12];
   int department;
};
```

I am confused on how to approach this problem if im reading data from a binary file and the data contains structs how can I reverse the order of the bits from big endian to little endian in that struct?

Comment: What about [`ntohs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) and friends?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without library functions?

Comment: @user2671024 Sure, but you would end up duplicating the functions almost word for word. Whats the point?

Comment: Converting between big endian and little endian pertains to byte ordering, not bit ordering. Within each byte the bit ordering is not changed.

Comment: Note that you just need to byte swap `age` and `department` - `name` will not be affected by endianness

Comment: Note the machines might have different sizes for integers as well, and the compilers might add a different amount of padding to the structures, so endianness might not be your only problem.

Comment: you should read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine

Comment: it effects byte ordering not bit ordering so here there is no problem if you are using the same structure in little and big endian machine .better to use "packet" attribute to make of fix pack of struct

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation to convert endianness:

```
// Convert from big to little or vice versa
void convert_record (struct record *bigLittle) {
    int x, temp;

    temp = bigLittle->age;

    for (x = 0; x < sizeof (int); x++) {
        ((char *)&(bigLittle->age))[x] = ((char *)&temp)[sizeof (int) - x]
    }

    temp = bigLittle->department;

    for (x = 0; x < sizeof (int); x++) {
        ((char *)&(bigLittle->department))[x] = ((char *)&temp)[sizeof (int) - x]
    }

    return;
}
```

However, as Michael Foukarakis has pointed out above, you really ought to use [`ntohs`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) and friends.