# Pointer type of smaller size than variable

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

Working with embedded systems, in order to have more resolution in a incremental sequence, I have two variables, one always following the other.

Specifically, I set a goal value using a 8 bits variable, but to go from one point (current value) to another I do it using 32 bits steps.

For example (that is a stupid example, but it just to show how I want to use it, in my code there are some temporizations which require the 32 bits varaibles to allow a slow change):

```
/* The variables */
char goal8bits;         // 8 bits
long int current32bits; // 32 bits    
char current8bits;      // 8 bits    
long int step32bits;    // 32 bits

/* The main function (in the real code that is done periodically with a specific period) */
current32bits = CONVERT_8BITS_TO_32BITS(current8bits);  // E.g: 0xAB -> 0xABABABAB
if (goal8bits < current8bits) {
   current32bits += step32bits;
}
current8bits = CONVERT_32BITS_TO_8BITS(current32bits);  // E.g: 0x01234567 -> 0x01

/* Other parts of the code */
I use current8bits to know the current value in the middle of a transition.
```

My question is if I can use a char pointer and make it point to the 32 bits variable one, so I do not need to update it each time I change it.
The previous example will look like this:

```
/* The variables */
char goal8bits;         // 8 bits
long int current32bits; // 32 bits
char *current8bits = (char *)&current32bits;      // Pointer to 8 bits
long int step32bits;    // 32 bits

/* The main function (in the real code that is done periodically with a specific period) */
if (goal8bits < *current8bits) {
   current32bits += step32bits;
}

/* Other parts of the code */
I will use *current8bits to know the current value in the middle of a transition.
```

Do you see any problem in doing that? Can it lead to a problem wih endianism?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with endianness. The result of `*current8bits` depends on the platform's endianness.

Comment: Yes, this should work if you take care with the endianness. Of course this type of bit-twiddling may inhibit other optimizations so have you checked that your compiler doesn't already generate the desired code for extracting the most-significant 8 bits through a shift? Not all embedded compilers are entirely hopeless you know, just most of them..

Comment: I might miss the point, but what would be the advantage of the first part's extending to 32 bits instead of directly calculating on the 8 bit values? Depending on the architecture (I assume a 32 Bitter - Cortex-M?), this may even be faster and more compact in 32 bits than some suspectible conversions (endianess!) using casts you will have a hard time to understand when looking at this code after some months. Also, you should use `stdint.h` instead of assuming long to be 32 bits and char 8 bits! Not to speak of char's signed-ness being left to the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the endianless of your system, and it is static you have to select from

```
char *current8bits = (char *)&current32bits;
```

or

```
char *current8bits = (((char *)&current32bits)+3);
```

If you have to test it, and your system cannot give you such of info you can derive it at application startup

```
uint32_t temp = 0x01020304;
uint8_t *temp2 = (uint8_t *)(&temp);
if (*temp2 == 0x01)
{
   char *current8bits = (char *)&current32bits;
}
else
{
   char *current8bits = (((char *)&current32bits)+3);
}
```

Another good solution is the top-voted and checked-as-answered answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine).

Comment: That "macro" (its a function actually) compares `char` with `void *`. Wouldn't call that "good". Also, gcc provides macros for this [already](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Comment: @Olaf OP Is talking about embedded system. Cross compiler and toolchains are not always derived from gcc. In many case you have to deal with very poor libs and compiler/linker options. Those solutions could work well with very basic systems.

Comment: I know the endianism of my system (in fact I have who, one for simulation and other for the real micro) so I solve it with a macro for my the initialization of the pointer to do the same as you commented depending on the current system.

The use of a macro is just to make it clearer what i am doing.

Thank you!

Comment: @LPs: "gcc provides ..." does not imply I expect him to use it. It is just a hint his compiler/cpp might also have some support for this. Wheter he uses Keil, IAR, sdcc or anything else (some commercial toolchains use gcc - Microchip for instance, iirc Atmel, too). However, there are still better ways without pointers (using a union for instance); Also, I still see no advantage. To me the question has the smell of an XY-problem.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not getting you. Where the code I [LINKED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine) is comparing char to void *?

Comment: @LPs: `return (test_endian[0] == NULL)`!

Comment: @Olaf Last comment: I was referring to the top voted answer, not to the question.

Comment: @LPs: There are currently two answers with the same number of votes. If you refer to _your_ answer, you might have noticed that I commented that, neither the question nor the other answer. You might have missed that we are talking about `C`, not `C++` (where comparing `char` to the macro `NULL` would still be bad style). So, you still have to prove me wrong. Oh, and regarding "embedded": you might have a look at my profile. Just a hint.

Comment: @Olaf lol. In the question I [LINKED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine) there is only one top-voted and checked-as-correct ansswer: the one with 60 upvotes...

Comment: Ok, that was not clear to me; your last comment now made it clear (one should always express clearly what is meant). Well, that's exactly how I would have done it (see my other comment - didn't read the referenced answer until now). However, I still suspect the question _here_ is actually not the right one. But without more information ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is endian dependent code, to make it portable you can use a mask and the left shift operator:

```
uint8_t goal8bits = 0x01;               // 8 bits
uint32_t current32bits = 0x01234567;    // 32 bits
uint32_t step32bits = 1;                // 32 bits

if (goal8bits < ((current32bits & 0xFF000000) >> 24)) {
    current32bits += step32bits;
}
```

Comment: That might generate even more code than the original version, depending on toolchain and target arch.