# Endianness macro in C

Tags: c, macros, endianness

I recently saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine) about endianness macros in C and I can't really wrap my head around the first answer.

> Code supporting arbitrary byte orders, ready to be put into a file
>   called order32.h:

```
#ifndef ORDER32_H
#define ORDER32_H

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
#error "unsupported char size"
#endif

enum
{
    O32_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 0x03020100ul,
    O32_BIG_ENDIAN = 0x00010203ul,
    O32_PDP_ENDIAN = 0x01000302ul
};

static const union { unsigned char bytes[4]; uint32_t value; } o32_host_order =
    { { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };

#define O32_HOST_ORDER (o32_host_order.value)

#endif
```

> You would check for little endian systems via
>
> `O32_HOST_ORDER == O32_LITTLE_ENDIAN`

I do understand endianness in general. This is how I understand the code:

1. Create example of little, middle and big endianness.
2. Compare test case to examples of little, middle and big endianness and decide what type the host machine is of.

What I don't understand are the following aspects:

1. Why is an union needed to store the *test-case*? Isn't `uint32_t` guaranteed to be able to hold 32 bits/4 bytes as needed? And what does the assignment `{ { 0, 1, 2, 3 } }` mean? It assigns the value to the union, but why the *strange* markup with two braces?
2. Why the check for `CHAR_BIT`? One comment mentions that it would be more useful to check `UINT8_MAX`? Why is `char` even used here, when it's not guaranteed to be 8 bits wide? Why not just use `uint8_t`? I found [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromedeveditor/blob/master/ide/nacl_android_rsa/endian.cc) link to Google-Devs github. They don't rely on this check... Could someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is a union needed to store the test case?

*The entire point of the test is to alias the array with the magic value the array will create.*

Isn't `uint32_t` guaranteed to be able to hold 32 bits/4 bytes as needed?

*Well, more-or-less.  It* will *but other than 32 bits there are no guarantees. It would fail only on some really fringe architecture you will never encounter.*

And what does the assignment `{ { 0, 1, 2, 3 } }` mean? It assigns the value to the union, but why the strange markup with two braces?

*The inner brace is for the array.*

Why the check for `CHAR_BIT?`

*Because that's the actual guarantee. If that doesn't blow up, everything will work.*

One comment mentions that it would be more useful to check `UINT8_MAX?` Why is char even used here, when it's not guaranteed to be 8 bits wide?

*Because in fact it always is, these days.*

Why not just use `uint8_t?` I found this link to Google-Devs github. They don't rely on this check... Could someone please elaborate?

*Lots of other choices would work also.*

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it the data is guaranteed to be stored consecutively in memory when initialized with the array initializer. And the endianness can be tested afterwards when addressed via `uint32_t`. Actually I do get an error, when I try to use the macro 032_HOST_ORDER. `error: invalid suffix '_HOST_ORDER' on integer constant.`. Do you have an idea, what is happening here?

Comment: Yeah the first letter is supposed to be an O *oh* and not a zero.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization has two set of braces because the inner braces initialize the `bytes` array.  So `byte[0]` is 0, `byte[1]` is 1, etc.

The union allows a `uint32_t` to lie on the same bytes as the `char` array and be interpreted in whatever the machine's endianness is.  So if the machine is little endian, `0` is in the low order byte and `3` is in the high order byte of `value`.  Conversely, if the machine is big endian, `0` is in the high order byte and `3` is in the low order byte of `value`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now. I do get an error though, when I try to access `032_HOST_ORDER` - `error: invalid suffix '_HOST_ORDER' on integer constant`. Do you have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: Typo: Should be `O32_HOST_ORDER`, not `032_HOST_ORDER`.  Identifiers can't begin with a digit.

Comment: Ohh, I'm stupid. Thank you really much - you just saved me.

Answer (score 2):

`{{0, 1, 2, 3}}` is the initializer for the union, which will result in `bytes` component being filled with `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

Now, since the `bytes` array and the `uint32_t` occupy the same space, you can read the same value as a native 32-bit integer. The value of that integer shows you how the array was shuffled - which really means which endian system are you using.

There are only 3 popular possibilities here - `O32_LITTLE_ENDIAN`, `O32_BIG_ENDIAN`, and `O32_PDP_ENDIAN`.

As for the `char` / `uint8_t` - I don't know. I think it makes more sense to just use `uint_8` with no checks.