# Is this C99 IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN macro portable?

Tags: c, endianness

While looking for a compile-time endian detection macro I found this:

```
#define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN (1 == *(unsigned char *)&(const int){1})
```

According to [an answer to *C Macro definition to determine big endian or little endian machine?*](/a/14272916), this can be evaluated at compile-time (at least with GCC) and doesn't assume any memory alignment. Is this really portable (provided C99 is available) and if so what are the caveats of this macro?

Comment: Regarding compile-time evaluation, I'm not sure that's a constant expression. For example, I don't think you could have something like `int x[IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN ? 10 : 20];` at file scope.

Comment: I'm not sure how portable anything related to "endianness" is. There's no requirement at all that there are only two kinds of endianness. A hypothetical architecture could easily have padding in its integral representations, or arrange the bits in some non-sequential way.

Comment: @KerrekSB It compiles in clang with `-Wall -std=c11`

Comment: @KerrekSB - C11 has a well defined notion of what is a constant expression. And a conditional expression is one such thing if all operands are themselves constant expressions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Does that include the cast? (Yes, the conditional expression is of course fine, but I was concerned about the cast in the comparison expression.) Reworded.

Comment: @KerrekSB - In this particular case, I think not [ see [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p8) ]. But it's not disallowed in general.

Comment: @KerrekSB My mistake, it does **not** compile at file scope. I had my declaration in a function scope (oops).

Comment: So is the cast to char* the reason its not a constant expression?

Comment: @user2711115 - You got it.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, could the use of a union instead of a cast be helpful here? edit: something like this #define IS_BIG_ENDIAN (!(union { uint16_t u16; unsigned char c; }){ .u16 = 1 }.c) from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2100549/2711115

Comment: @user2711115 - Not really. The union is not considered a constant expression either (its address is, if you create a compound literal at file scope), but I don't know how that can be useful to you.

Comment: @user2711115 I do not think there is any way you can do this and have the resulting expression be a compile time constant. The fundamental problem is, I think, that the compiler does not necessarily know the endianness of the target platform.

Comment: @StoryTeller The cast to char* isn't the reason, it's the compound literal that is not a constant.

Comment: @2501 - At file scope, the compound literal is a static object, and taking its address produces a constant expression.

Comment: @StoryTeller That is not relevant to what I'm talking about. You agreed that the cast to char* is the reason the expression isn't a constant. That is not correct. I want to point that out so OP won't be mislead.

Comment: @2501 - The cast to char* invalidates the expression from being a CE either way. At block scope, it's the literals address that isn't a CE, but what difference does it make any way? The OP can't use that macro as CE endianess indicator. There is nothing misleading about telling them that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed no undefined behaviour here so it's portable in that sense.

But the condition doesn't *necessarily* prove `IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN`ness.

The storage arrangements of an `int` are largely left to the implementation. There are other choices other than the classical little and big endian schemes, and your macro could yield a false positive.

Comment: It's not a portable constant expression, which is what I believe the OP was asking.

Comment: You might be right on a second reading. Let's see how this answer fares in the voting process.

Comment: Well, the point about it not really testing endianess well, kind of renders the constant expression discussion moot. So you know my opinion vote-wise :)

Comment: "The storage arrangements of an int are left purely to the implementation." Not entirely sure if this is correct. C allows three different kinds of signedness format. The mostly fictional _one's complement_ and _sign & magnitude_ may have padding bits. I don't see how this code would fail even on such fictional systems though. I suppose it might be better to use `unsigned int`, but it isn't a grave sin to assume that your code will only be executed on computers that actually exist in the real world.

Comment: "The mostly fictional one's complement and sign & magnitude may have padding bits" I had that in mind when I answered, without the "mostly fictional" bit. The problem I have with these sort of macros is folk assume they are definitive. But I have dropped the word "purely", replacing with "largely".

Comment: "There is indeed no undefined behaviour here so it's portable" --> Hmm, I tried compiling `#define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN (1 == *(unsigned char *)&(const int){1})
#if IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN
  int test;
#endif` with "error: operator '==' has no right operand".  So unclear how this is portable, if it does not compile.