# MISRA compliant run-time detection of endianness

Tags: c, runtime, endianness, c99, misra

(First note that I know determining endianness at run-time is not an ideal solution and there are better ideas. Please don't bring that up)

I need to check the endianness of my CPU at run-time. I also have to do it while staying MISRA-compliant. I'm using C99.

MISRA doesn't allow conversion between different types of pointers, so simply casting a `uint32_t*` to `uint8_t*` and de-referencing to see what value the `uint8_t` holds is not allowed. Using `union`s is also out of the question (MISRA doesn't allow `union`s).

I also attempted to use `memcmp` like in the following piece of code:

```
static endi get_endianess(void)
{
    uint32_t a = 1U;
    uint8_t b = 1U;

    return memcmp(&a, &b, 1) == 0 ? endi_little : endi_big;
}
```

but MISRA says that `The pointer arguments to the Standard Library function 'memcmp' are not pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types`, meaning I've failed to out-smart it by converting to legal `void*` pointers and letting `memcmp` do the dirty work.

Any other clever ideas will be appreciated. If you don't have a MISRA checker, just send me your idea and I'll let you know what my checker says

Comment: There appears to be something that might help you _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103095/645128)_

Comment: Out of curiosity, **why** you need run-time detection? endianness will not change from run to run!

Comment: I, too, would be interested to know why it must be done at run time.  But if you must, anything stopping you from using `endian.h`? `return __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN ? endi_little : endi_big`

Comment: Also, I noticed that you tagged the question `C99` but mentioned `C11` in the question.  I don't know that it really affects your question so much, but last I knew, MISRA doesn't support `C11`.

Comment: Make it `char` instead of `uint8_t`. Will it still complain?

Comment: @ryyker Most examples use a union which is not allowed. I tried the compound literals one and it failed for `Operand to a unary operator has an inappropriate essential type 'unsigned char'`


@SergeyA It's a very boring reason, hard to explain, no good reason


@ChristianGibbons endian.h is not available on some of my targets


@ChristianGibbons I meant to say C99, my bad


@EugeneSh. Yes, it still complains


Thank you all some much for your attempts to help though

Comment: @SergeyA Except it can on Power PC, and in theory on ARM too (though I have yet to encounter a big endian ARM). But well, it would be complete madness to change endianess variably.

Comment: Also, the compiler isn't necessary able to reliably and portably detect endianess at compile-time.

Comment: @Lundin compiler might not be able, but `endian.h` should.

Comment: @SergeyA That's not even POSIX, just some Linux thing. Determining CPU endianess or swapping the byte order of integers isn't rocket science.

Comment: MISRA doesn't support C11 **yet** (but keep watching this space, for 24 hours or so...)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood the MISRA-C rules. Code such as this is fine:

```
 uint16_t u16 = 0xAABBu;
 bool big_endian = *(uint8_t*)&u16 == 0xAAu;
```

MISRA-C:2012 rule 11.3 has an exception allowing pointer conversions to pointer to character types (which `uint8_t` can safely be regarded as), but not the other way around. The purpose of the rule is to protect against misaligned access and strict aliasing bugs.

---

Also, MISRA allows `union` just fine, the rule against it is advisory, just to force people to stop and think *how* they are using unions. MISRA does not allow `union` for the sake of storing multiple unrelated things in the same memory area, such as creating *variants* and other such nonsense. But controlled type punning, where padding/alignment and endianess has been considered, can be used with MISRA. That is, if you don't like this advisory rule. Personally I always ignore it in my MISRA implementations.

Comment: +1 for the union observation... the Rule is there for a reason - which is that there is some dubious behavior, although most compilers do behave.

Answer (score 0):

In a MISRA context, I suppose this header and this function might not be available, but:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

static endi get_endianness(void)
{
    return htons(0x0001u) == 0x0001u ? endi_big : endi_little;
}
```

Comment: This header is not available on some of my targets, but thank you for the attempt

Comment: For the record, if you're shipping (they have) the standard library as compiled `.so` files (per target) along with a limited subset of the headers, then this function most likely already exists (within the `.so`), but is just unknown/not-exposed. If you `extern` the function prototype you would still be able to use it, despite not having the header.