# How to query target architecture endianness during gcc compilation?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, constexpr, endianness, compile-time

I would like to promote more of my endianness logic to compile time constexpr's. I know that in C++20, this is highly standardized via `std::endian`. However, for the moment I am targeting C++17.

How can I query the *target* architecture's endianness from within my C++ code? Prefer simple `constexpr` functions and macros to autoconf. Would appreciate working snippets for GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the compilers you mention? Especially what preprocessor macros they might define for identifying the target system?

Comment: Related to [c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675229/9072753 what research did you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use preprocessor defined macros of GCC like below

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
```

or

```
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

You've to include `#include <endian.h>` header

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform solution you can use [Boost.Predef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/predef/doc/index.html) which is a preprocessor header that even works with C. It contains various predefined macros for the target platform including the endianness ([BOOST_ENDIAN_*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/predef/doc/index.html#_boost_endian))

```
#if BOOST_ENDIAN_BIG_BYTE
    std::cout << "Big endian!";
#elif BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE
    std::cout << "Little endian!";
#endif
```